# QGraphicsView shifted its contents when scrollbar appear

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I noticed that QGraphicsView shifted its contents by few pixels upward when scrollbar appear. Is there anyway to avoid such behavior?. I want the scrollbar appear but the contents should stay at the same position.

Here is the sample codes:

```
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView v;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    v.show();

    v.setScene(&scene);
    QBrush brush(Qt::red);
    scene.addRect(0,0,1000,80,QPen(),brush);
    //When you reduce the width of v, scrollbar appear but contents shifted upward.
    return a.exec();
```

Comment: You will need to place this in a class - and create connects between your View `connect(v->horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
            this, SLOT(adjustZero()));` and similar to vertical scroll bar - map the initial "zero" position of the view to the scene - and then move the view by the current "zero" position.

Comment: @Thalia: look like it doesnt work. Can you have example codes for adjustZero function?